# Exibir nome do usuário logado no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, login, wordpress-theme

Tenho um site em wordpress, uso o template TOTAL.

Nesse template, no topo do site aparece a mensagem login para o usuário logar, e ela muda para logout quando o usuário já esta logado e quer sair.
Gostaria apenas que nesse campo também mostra-se o nome do usuário, não sei como fazer isso.
Segue o código que tem nessa área.

```
<span class="wpex-inline">
[font_awesome icon="user"] [wp_login_url text="Entrar" logout_text="Sair"]</span>
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda!